# converting a file of this format "file.csv.url" file to file.excel

Tags: excel, csv, graph-databases

I have a csv file in the format ,"display_relation_associated with.csv.url".[this is how it is opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX1Hl.jpg) I want to open this in excel but when I do it,it is giving me the html code of the url. Please tell me how to convert this data which is in the fornat csv.url to the format of excel
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRm7d.png)

this csv file was originally a subset of a bigger file.The bigger file had information about diseases as a graph in csv format stored in excel. I separated the files based on a unique value in a single column through the following code in jupyter notebook.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
Data_Dir=r"C:\Users\Vikram\.Neo4jDesktop\relate-data\dbmss\dbms-9b8d0ef8-b027-4aec-a0da-4a7e4890bd15\import"
Dataset_file="kg_raw.csv"

# read the large csv file into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(Data_Dir,Dataset_file))

#get the unique values of the column you want to split the data by
row_values = df["display_relation"].unique()

# loop over the unique values of the column
for value in row_values:
    # create a dataframe for each unique value
    value_df = df[df["display_relation"] == value]

    # write the dataframe to a new csv file
    value_df.to_csv(f'{"display_relation"}_{value}.csv', index=False)
```

I ran this in jupyter notebook and I got about 18 unique files. But I am only able to open it in jupyter notebook's localhost, when I try to open it in excel I get a html code. I tried the same in a website called gigasheet and separated the bigger excel file into chunks based on the unique values of the column "display_relation"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHzQJ.png). But I am not able to download the individual chunks, in this. What can I do to get the individual chunks as an excel? That is what can I do to get the separated files in csv.url format to be in excel?

Comment: You seem to be confusing yourself. In the first screenshot, you have the text `display_relation_associated with.csv` open inside Jupyter. That file is the text content you want. You want to save that file to somewhere Excel can easily access it or move the copy of `display_relation_associated with.csv` somewhere. It will just be text. Open it with a coding text editor like VSCode or Sublime Text (Not Microsoft Word or Word.exe or Notepad.) It should look just like your first screenshot. Open Excel and paste the contents of your first screenshot into Excel.

Comment: Your code block doesn't make anything that has the extension `.csv.url`, and so avoid any of those files. I worry you are doing something between your first screenshot and Excel to make something ending in `.csv.url` and confusing yourself.  However, if that is the only thing your script is making that would be weird, but if the content of those files looks like your first screenshot, then try just removing the `.url` and then opening that with Excel. If things still aren't making sense, go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) and press `launch binder`. A temporary ...

Comment: <continued> remote session will open in your browser after a few minutes. Open a new notebook & paste in your code block. Then add a way to get the data file in there. The easiest would be to drag and drop `kg_raw.csv` into the file navigation panel on the left side to add it to remote computer. Then change the line 7 to read `df = pd.read_csv("kg_raw.csv")`. Then try running your code and see what happens. That should make files ending in `.csv` that you can right-click on in the file navigator & download back to your local system. The extension should stay only as `.csv` with nothing after.